# How to get the Response Message and Response Code when the Assertion Fails in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I am working on Webservice Testing using Jmeter.I am using Beanshell Assertion In this I am trying to display the Response Code and Response Message but the problem is when the Request Fails I am unable to get the response Code|Message displayed on my jmeter log file.In case If I get the Proper response I am getting the Response Code|Message Properly.Is there any solution to get the Response Code|Message when the Request Fails in jmeter BeanShell Assertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something is wrong with your Beanshell code as Beanshell Assertion should normally handle parent sampler failure

[image: Beanshell Assertion example]

The code which produced these log lines looks as simple as:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Sampler: ");
sb.append(SampleResult.getSampleLabel()).append(" ");
sb.append("Successful: ");
sb.append(SampleResult.isSuccessful()).append(" ");
sb.append("Code: ");
sb.append(ResponseCode).append(" ");
sb.append("Message: ");
sb.append(ResponseMessage);

log.info(sb.toString());
```

Few tips:

1. Add `debug();` statement as 1st line of your Beanshell Assertion and inspect STDOUT for details
2. Surround your code in try/catch block and in the catch block print exception to jmeter.log file as

   ```
   try {
       //your Beanshell Assertion code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Something went wrong", ex)
   }
   ```
3. See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for details on proper Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: thanks Dmitri T.based on your code i was able to find out the problem.

Comment: Is It possible to get the assertion Failure message that is displayed in the View Result Tree to be stored into a String Variable

Comment: just use `vars.put("variable_name", "variable_value");` stanza

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a their standard listener

Add "View Results Tree"